# how to configure jenkins via chefzero vagrant provisioner

Tags: chef, vagrant, jenkins

using the jenkins cookbook 2.2.2

==> https://supermarket.chef.io/cookbooks/jenkins

i can bring up jenkins in vagrant vm using chef_zero provisioner with

`chef.run_list = [
        'recipe[jenkins::master]',
]`

however, i am trying to install plugins and create a new job from erb template, and i am having no luck.   my understanding is that configuration should be passed using the "chef.json" datastructure with chef zero.   I have tried many many syntax configurations, but no luck (and no error, as it appears if not correct, it is just ignored)

here is an example of installing a plugin that is not working (i guess the question is how does one configure a chef resource within a recipe inside of vagrant with chef_zero provision):

`chef.json = {
  'java' =>  {
    'jdk_version'   => '7',
  },
  'jenkins' => {
    'master' => {
      'jenkins_plugin' => [ 'job-dsl', 'groovy', 'git', 'packer' ]
    }
  }
}`

i would be very grateful if anyone could provide a working example of the chef.json that vagrant chef_zero provisioner wants to install jenkins plugin (and/or installing a new job from erb template or xml file)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the answer is plugins and jobs cannot be directly invoked by the community jenkins cookbook.   a wrapper cookbook needs to be made (which depends on jenkins).

this is done by creating a blank cookbook:

`knife cookbook create jenkins_wrapper`

adding community cookbook dependancy (jenkins_wrapper/metadata.rb):

`depends 'jenkins'`

and then making it do something (jenkins_wrapper/recipes/default.rb):

`jenkins_plugin 'git' 
jenkins_plugin 'job-dsl'`

additionally, if using berkshelf, you must add path to cookbook in Berksfile:

`cookbook 'jenkins_wrapper', path: '/path/to/jenkins_wrapper'`

(this path can be relative)

it took me a few hours to figure this all out, so hopefully this will help someone else save some time

Answer (score 0):

You can give a look at [this](http://javidea.blogspot.it/2015/05/installing-and-configuring-jenkins.html).
Maybe it could be helpful

Comment: Welcome to ServerFault! While the article you link to may well be helpful, you should try to avoid posting link-only answers; try to include the useful content in your answer such that it does not rely solely on the link itself.